# Space Invaders pygame: Only 2 enemies will display in a row

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame, space

[image: screenshot of game window]

The row is meant to be filled with enemies, however only 2 appear.

What is meant to happen is that the enemies are supposed to appear at the top of the screen and fill the screen without blitting forever. However it only blits two of these enemies and the `for` loop doesn't add any more to the group, why?

Main File Code:

```
# main game loop
def mainGame():
    gameRunning = True # boolean variable to show the main game loop is running

    aliens = Group()# Make a group to store the aliens in

    # create a fleet of aliens
    gf.create_fleet(spaceSettings, display, ship, aliens)

    # main game event loop
    while gameRunning: # while gameRunning is true the following will continuously occur
        gf.checkEvents(spaceSettings, display, ship, bullets) # runs the alternate events loop in game functions
        ship.update() # updates the ships movement
        gf.updateBullets(bullets) # updates the bullets movement and display
        gf.updateScreen(spaceSettings, display, ship, aliens, bullets) # updating the screen with the relevant images
```

Game Functions:

```
from alien import Alien # importing the alien class

def create_fleet(spaceSettings, display, ship, aliens):
    """Create a fleet of aliens."""
    # Create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
    alien = Alien(spaceSettings, display)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(spaceSettings, alien.rect.width)

    # create the fleet of aliens

    for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
        create_alien(spaceSettings, display, aliens, alien_number)+

def get_number_aliens_x(spaceSettings, alien_width):
    """How many aliens will fit in a row."""
    available_space_x = spaceSettings.displayWidth - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x

def create_alien(spaceSettings, display, aliens, alien_number):
    """Create an alien and place it in a row."""
    alien = Alien(spaceSettings, display)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    aliens.add(alien)
    print(aliens)
```

Comment: What's the console output? What is it printing?

Comment: @Yserbius its printing that 2 sprites are inside the group and no more are added when it is supposed to fill the row until there is no available space on the screen

Comment: What's value does `number_aliens_x` get assigned to it in the `create_fleet()` function? Maybe it's incorrect for some reason.

Comment: @martineau the value this is assigned should be the x position of the aliens

Comment: Well, that's not what it looks like—which is that it controls the ***number*** of aliens that are created by the `for`, which isn't the same thing as their x position. If its value is calculated incorrect, it might cause too few (or even too many) of them to be created.

Comment: @martineau I will play about with it and get back to you if I solve it. Thank you for the perspective :)

Comment: @martineau yes you are right, it seems that the number_aliens_x dictated how many aliens were blitted onto the screen. Thank you because I can now control how many are blitted, problem solved!

Comment: If you've fixed the problem on your own, you can answer your own question. Also, please read the [mcve page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the number_aliens_x dictated how many aliens were blitted onto the screen.